# How to half frequency of triangle wave

Tags: frequency, wave

I wanted to know if there is a method/circuit to half the frequency of a triangle wave, in the same way a flip flop can be used to half the frequency of a square wave. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: This really depends on what qualities you need, the frequency, and most especially what the application is.

Comment: Halving a square wave takes advantage of some shortcuts: the 0-180 degree output all 0, and the 180-359 degree output is all 1. So for square wave there is no need to estimate the output. But for triangle wave the output has to slowly ramp up or down, at a different rate than the input... I think the simplest way to accomplish this would be using a phase locked loop, so you would need to consider the trade-offs of how much the input signal is allowed to vary and how rapidly the output needs to respond vs how accurate the output must be. It's not going to be simple.